# UIButton does not appear at last row of last section in UItableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to implement the table view with 4 cells in each section and number of section is also 2. I added the buy button in last two rows of each sections and make them hidden till row is not selected. When I click on last row of the first section, the buy button appears. However, as soon as I tap on last row of second section (last section) than it do not appears. Here is my code.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
 *)indexPath 
 {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// some code for cell properties

    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {   
      if(indexPath.row==2)
        {                
            //some code for property of buy button1

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.accessoryView = buyButton1;
            [buyButton1 setHidden:YES];
        }
      if(indexPath.row==3)
        {                              
          //some code for property of buy button2
          cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
          cell.accessoryView = buyButton2;
          [buyButton2 setHidden:YES];
        }
    }    

    if(indexPath.section==1)
    {   
       if(indexPath.row==2)
        {

            //some code for property of buy button3
            [cell addSubview:buyButton3];
            [buyButton3 setHidden:TRUE];

        }
        if(indexPath.row==3)
        {

            buyButton4= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            buyButton4.frame = CGRectMake(194, 4, 70, 37);
            [buyButton4 setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [buyButton4 addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            buyButton4.tag = 4;
            [cell addSubview:buyButton4];
            [buyButton4 setHidden:TRUE];

        }
    } 

}
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
  cell.textLabel.text = [privateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}    
else
{
  cell.textLabel.text = [workArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
return cell;
}
```

Here is my code for selection of row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

[tableViewForOccasion deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

NSArray *visibleCells = [tableViewForOccasion visibleCells];

for (UITableViewCell *aCell in visibleCells) 
{
    aCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
if(indexPath.section==1)
{
  if(indexPath.row==3)
   {
     [buyButton4 setHidden:FALSE];
   }
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are talking about the last row in the second section then your checking condition is wrong

```
if(indexPath.section==1)
{
  if(indexPath.row==3) // you have mistake in this part where you had if(indexPath.row==2)
   {
     [buyButton4 setHidden:FALSE];
   }
}
```

Comment: ooops! sorry my mistake, its if(indexPath.row==3) but i pasted over here is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you forgot the `buyButton4` allocation and `setHidden = FALSE`. 

//Replace Your Code

if(indexPath.row==3)
        {
        UIButton * buyButton4 =[[UIButton alloc] init];
            buyButton4= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            buyButton4.frame = CGRectMake(194, 4, 70, 37);
            [buyButton4 setTitle:@"Buy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [buyButton4 addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            buyButton4.tag = 4;
            [cell addSubview:buyButton4];
            [buyButton4 setHidden:FALSE];

        }
```

Comment: where to allocate? I allocated in viewdidload firstly but didn't work than i added in cellForRowatIndex..no luck . :(

Comment: but i want to [buyButton4 setHidden:TRUE]; when cell is created and click on row should display buy button.